# (Fedora 25) Change Screen Brightness Using Function Keys (ASUS TP300L)

Tags: fedora, brightness, asus

Before even beginning to share the problem, I understand that this issue has been brought up a number of times, on different websites. Literally beaten to death. But unfortunately none of the solution worked for me.

Onto the case in point, I recently installed Fedora 25 (64 bit) on Asus TP300L (planning to get rid of Windows 10 altogether!) and everything is working just fine except for the brightness keys. I just can't get them to work :/

**Solutions tried:**

1. `xbacklight` has always been my goto module but it failed on Fedora installations. I get an error saying no matching display found (I cannot remember the exact error though).
2. I learned about `xrandr` using the same trickry as that of `xbacklight` (or rather the other way around) but it seems like `xrandr` isn't available in Wayland.
3. Tried editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (grub was saved each time) and added (individually),

   1. `acpi_backlight=vendor`
   2. `acpi_backlight=video`
   3. `acpi_backlight=native`
   4. `acpi_backlight=`
   5. `acpi_backlight=none` 
      without any success.
4. (I didn't expect this to work since it has more to do with Xorg) Created `20-intel.conf` under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` with following content,

   ```
   Section "Device"
           Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
           Driver      "intel"
           BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
           Option      "Backlight"       "intel_backlight"
   EndSection
   ```
5. Lastly, I tried to create a custom acpi event and registering the combination of function key and Ctrl but I wasn't able to use `acpi_listen`.

The brightness indicator is working just fine, just the functions don't work. So, I am guessing Fedora is handling brightness behavior just fine, its the keys which are creating trouble.

Disclaimer - I am quite new to Fedora and so it would be great if any commands you share are accompanied by some description. I can 'man' up the rest!

System Info: Asus TP300L (Model), No dedicated graphics card, Kernel 4.8.16

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with my Asus Zenbook UX310U and have also tried the steps you mentioned. Every other function key except the brightness keys produce ACPI commands and work, but I cant for the life of me get the brightness keys to work

Comment: How were you able to see the acpi command for button? I cannot use acpi_listen. It worked on Ubuntu installation though.

Comment: I was able to use acpi_listen, which blocked and then wrote a line of output everytime I pressed a function key. It did this for every function key *except* the ones that control the screen brightness

Comment: Interesting. I cannot even use acpi_listen, keep on getting `bash: acpi_listen: command not found...` error :/

Comment: Oh, you do need to install it first. On Fedora, its part of the `acpid` package I think

Comment: I had the `acpid` package but wasn't able to use `acpi_listen`, it returned `acpi_listen: can't open socket /var/run/acpid.socket: No such file or directory` error. Starting the acpid service `systemctl start acpid.service` sorted it out. Anyway, I will see if I can create a custom acpi event.

Comment: @ErinDrummond I have the brightness keys working (partially)! Finally. Check the answer but in particular, kernel update (to version 4.9.10) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently something changed with latest Kernel update (i.e. version 4.9.10). Following things are possible now,

1. Brightness keys are now being registered. I tested it in custom Keyboard setting.
2. xbacklight is working as expected. No more errors.

Here's what I did,

Mapped F5 and F6 keys (under All Settings -> Keyboard -> Click on '+' indicator) to commands "/usr/bin/xbacklight -inc 5" and "/usr/bin/xbacklight -dec 5" respectively.

The only gripe is function key is still not being registered but I can certainly live with this setup!

P.S - Make sure that xbacklight is indeed installed. Use `sudo dnf install xbacklight`